# How to plot a paired histogram using seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, seaborn

I would like to make a **paired histogram** like the one shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114151/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-bihistogram-plot) using the seaborn distplot.
This kind of plot can also be referred to as the **back-to-back histogram** shown [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/making-back-to-back-histograms/), or a **bihistogram** inverted/mirrored along the x-axis as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340338/back-to-back-histograms-in-matplotlib).

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

green = np.random.normal(20,10,1000)
blue = np.random.poisson(60,1000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))

sns.distplot(blue, hist=True, kde=True, hist_kws={'edgecolor':'black'}, kde_kws={'linewidth':2}, bins=10, color='blue')
sns.distplot(green, hist=True, kde=True, hist_kws={'edgecolor':'black'}, kde_kws={'linewidth':2}, bins=10, color='green')
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-20,121,20))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0.0,0.07,0.01))
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

Here is the output:
[image: seaborn distplot]

When I use the method discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340338/back-to-back-histograms-in-matplotlib) (plt.barh), I get the bar plot shown just below, which is not what I am looking for.
[image: horizontal bar plot]

Or maybe I haven't understood the workaround well enough...
A simple/short implementation of python-seaborn-distplot similar to [these](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114151/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-bihistogram-plot) kinds of plots would be perfect. I edited the figure of my first plot above to show the kind of plot I hope to achieve (though y-axis not upside down):
[image: paired histogram]

Any leads would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a possible approach using seaborn's displots.
Seaborn doesn't return the created graphical elements, but the `ax` can be interrogated. To make sure the `ax` only contains the elements you want upside down, those elements can be drawn first. Then, all the `patches` (the rectangular bars) and the `lines` (the curve for the kde) can be given their height in negative. Optionally the x-axis can be set at `y == 0` using `ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')`.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

green = np.random.normal(20, 10, 1000)
blue = np.random.poisson(60, 1000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))

sns.distplot(green, hist=True, kde=True, hist_kws={'edgecolor': 'black'}, kde_kws={'linewidth': 2}, bins=10,
             color='green')
for p in ax.patches:  # turn the histogram upside down
    p.set_height(-p.get_height())
for l in ax.lines:  # turn the kde curve upside down
    l.set_ydata(-l.get_ydata())

sns.distplot(blue, hist=True, kde=True, hist_kws={'edgecolor': 'black'}, kde_kws={'linewidth': 2}, bins=10,
             color='blue')
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-20, 121, 20))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0.0, 0.07, 0.01))
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

pos_ticks = np.array([t for t in ax.get_yticks() if t > 0])
ticks = np.concatenate([-pos_ticks[::-1], [0], pos_ticks])
ax.set_yticks(ticks)
ax.set_yticklabels([f'{abs(t):.2f}' for t in ticks])
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Answer (score 8):

You could use two subplots and invert the y-axis of the lower one and plot with the same bins.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.normal(0,5,1000), 'b': np.random.normal(20,5,1000)})

fig =plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)

bins = np.arange(-20,40)

ax.hist(df['a'], bins=bins)
ax2.hist(df['b'],color='orange', bins=bins)
ax2.invert_yaxis()
```

[image]

#### edit:

improvements suggested by @mwaskom

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True, figsize=(5,5))

bins = np.arange(-20,40)

for ax, column, color, invert in zip(axes.ravel(), df.columns, ['teal', 'orange'],  [False,True]):
    ax.hist(df[column], bins=bins, color=color)
    
    if invert:
        ax.invert_yaxis()
        
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Good, but share the x axes and then use `subplots_adjust` to zero out the `h_pad` and it will be great.

Comment: @mwaskom very nice ideas! I took the liberty to include them.